# How to use Where clause in a ICollection

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Hi I have a ICollection:

```
using System.Linq;
...
public virtual ICollection<MyObject> MyList { get; set; }
```

And want to get the first result or use a Where clause for find a result in the implemented property, for example:

```
var x = test.MyList.Where(c => c.MyId == 1);
```

But my object do not list the methods like Where or FirstOrDefault

Comment: Use `.First(c => c.MyId == 1)` or `.FirstOrDefault(c => c.MyId == 1)` and close question. Further reading http://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/

Comment: To improve future question please carefully read [MCVE] guidance on posting code.

Comment: I use System.Linq but does not work, why?

Comment: Why can't you provide sample that demonstrates the problem and exact error message? There is no way for others to know what did you do wrong to get seemingly correct code to fail at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var x = test.MyList.Where(c => c.MyId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work or listed the methods. My object is a ICollection

Comment: Try adding using System.Linq; to the using block (I guess you mean Visual Studio IntelliSense doesn't list the methods?)

Comment: I use System.Linq but does not work, why?